# Is XSS a vulnerability or an attack?

Tags: xss

Why so many people use different defenitions(attack or vulneraibility) for XSS?
I think that XSS is attack, that exploits insufficient filtering vulnerability. Am I right?

The answer for this question should unambiguously explain what is correct definition for XSS, with additional commenting, why people uses different definitions.

Comment: Code injection is the attack, XSS is the vulnerability.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

XSS is both a vulnerability and an attack.

If we were being very strict about terminology, we would say "my website has an XSS vulnerability" and "we logged an XSS attack at 08:43". Often for shorthand people just say "XSS" and leave you to imply from the context whether they mean a vulnerability or an attack.

I would say that "insufficient filtering" is not a vulnerability itself, it is a category of vulnerabilities, including: SQL injection, XPath injection, path traversal, etc. In fact, I would usually call this category "injection". An XSS vulnerability is an example of an injection vulnerability.

Answer (score 3):

As the definition says

> Cross-site scripting (XSS) is a type of computer security vulnerability typically found in Web applications. XSS enables attackers to inject client-side script into Web pages viewed by other users.
> Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

XSS is a vulnerability, because XSS-vulnerable site gives the attacker the opportunity to attack it using *script injection*. However it's also considered an *attack vector*, which is why probably people mix it with an attack.

In short

> XSS - vulnerability or an attack vector
>
> script injection  - attack technique

Regarding terminology, the difference/relation between **attack** and **vulnerability** is in short that the attack is an exploitation of a vulnerability. Therefore it is an action done in order to harm the target, after discovering the vulnerability.

Comment: Don't beat me for quoting Wiki, please ;)

Comment: I have seen a slightly different (and probably somehow better) definition of attack: Attack is an attempt (successful or not) to breach a system (maybe through a vulnerability, possibly through a phishing). So, you may even perform an XSS attack on a site that is not vulnerable, although the attack will not be successful :)

Answer (score 1):

XSS stands for Cross Site Scripting. So think about it, what is scripting? That's the *noun* form of the *verb* for the attack. You don't Cross-Site-Script (verb) unless you're attacking. It's not something you *do* to make a site vulnerable, it's something you do to compromise. Though as the marked-correct answer indicates, to be clear we should indicate which form we mean, because frankly, my argument is nothing more than pedantic linguistics. (So is the question really!) ;-)